# Store Initial Value of 'SensorEvent.sensor' Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I'm creating a *step-counter* that I want to reset daily using the `SensorEvent.sensor` & `Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER`. I know this should be possible by saving the initial value of the array and subtracting the current value. The problem is that *arrays are immutable*. Is there a workaround to subtract an array against itself to get 0, yet still make it count?

My current code sets the value to 0, but won't count because both variables come from the same array.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skritt, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.skrittText);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
        return myView;

}    

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
   float[] values = event.values;

    int value = -1;
    final int value1 =(int) values[0];
    int value2 = 0;


        if (values.length > 0) {
            value = (int) values[0];
        }


        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
            value2 = value - value1;

            textView.setText("" + value2);

        } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
            // For test only. Only allowed value is 1.0 i.e. for step taken
            textView.setText("" + value);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the initial value in a global and subtract it each time you get an update.